# Filter Words from One List with Words from Another

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming

I'm a relatively new programmer learning scala and functional programming through a udemy class.

I am seeking to filter a list of strings based on another list of strings. I would like to reduce the first list down, so that when I print it out, it only contains the words - "rob", "learns", "scala"

Here's the code I am working with:

```html
val list1:Array[String] = Array("rob","you", "to","learns", "your", "the","scala", "a")

val badWords:Array[String] = Array("you", "to", "your", "the", "a")

val list2 = list1.map(x => badWords.map(badWord => list1.filter(word => word != badWord)))

for (word <- list2) {
  println(word)
}
```

My logic is that for each word from list1, I then try to compare each badWord element against the current list1 item to determine if it should be filtered or not.

I have run this successfully by hardcoding in what I want to have filtered, such as `val list2 = list1.filter(_ != "to")`. Obviously, I want give this the capability to scale, so I would like to learn how to pair the filter and map functions (if that is the correct approach).

Thanks in advance, let me know if I should provide further information or context.

Comment: `list1 diff badWords`

Comment: yes that is what I was looking to achieve

Comment: Dont use diff, it wont remove more than one instance of a bad word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a very simple snippet for this:

```
list1.filter(!badWords.contains(_))
```

This will remove all the words that are also in the badWords List. Im not sure if this will work with arrays however so I suggest using Lists instead.

Example:

```
val words = List("Hello", "Hello", "World")
val badWords = List("Hello")
val filteredWords = words.filter(!badWords.contains(_))
```

Comment: I checked it and it was successful!

Comment: Someone also commented that you could do the following: `val list2 = list1.filterNot(badWords.contains)`       - same thing you have suggested, just different syntax

Comment: In general case wouldn't you want to convert `badWords` to a `Set` because look up time in `Set` is O(1), while it is O(n) in `List`.